# "increasingly globalized world" , can it be "increasingly globalizing world" if I were to talk in present continuous manner?

Tags: tense, adverbs, present-continuous

Is this sentence correct?

> there are 280 million French speakers in this increasingly **globalizing** world

if not, what's wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Be aware that you're switching to the "active" verb usage (the world which is globalizing ***itself***), as opposed to the "passive" reference to a *world which is increasingly **globalised*** (being changed by unnamed "external" forces). But in practice that's probably a meaningless distinction for most people.

Comment: Think French: globalisant versus globalisé, same difference.